What is the translation of lawfare in French?
Lawfare is:

the strategic use of legal proceedings to intimidate or hinder an opponent.

Example 1:

Not cool of them to try (for the third time) to impede SpaceX’s progress by lawfare. [Elon Musk]

Example 2:

But the use of lawfare as an alternative to fighting elections would have confirmed his worst fears. [Times, Sunday Times (2014)]

What is the translation of lawfare in French?


https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english-french?q=lawfare returned no results.
https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/lawfare returned no results. ("law fare" returned no results as well).
Google Translate returns "le recours au droit" which doesn't convey the "to intimidate or hinder an opponent" part.
https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=lawfare returned  « guerre de la loi », which I'm not sure is the best option.


On parle souvent d'intimidation judiciaire.
On trouve aussi:

Abus du droit d'ester en justice

Procédure-bâillon


L'OQLF France Terme recommande

Guerre juridique


Le fondement d'une guerrilla juridique est l'instrumentalisation du droit.
